# Problem with array initialization as instance variable in Java

Tags: java, javafx

my problem is that when i am trying to get some objects from array that i declared as instance variable I am getting null instead of object that i put inside my array. As i know, arrays should be automatically initialized as any other instance variables if we will set some default values. I will explain it in details in code below:

```
public class GameBoardAI implements IGameModel{


    Random rand = new Random();
    int currentPlayer = 1;
    TicTacViewController tacController = new  TicTacViewController();
    Button[] buttonss = new Button[]{ tacController.btn1, tacController.btn2, tacController.btn3, tacController.btn4, 
            tacController.btn5, tacController.btn6, tacController.btn7, tacController.btn8, tacController.btn9};
```

Here is start of my class, and here is method I am trying to use:

```
public void switchPlayer() {
    if(currentPlayer == 1)
    {              
        currentPlayer=2;
        buttonss[rand.nextInt(9)].fire();

    }
    if(currentPlayer == 2)
        currentPlayer = 1;

}
```

You can see here, that I am trying to get some random button, from array of buttons i created in instance variable. Another confusing thing is that everything is working well, when I am making an array as a local variable inside method, instead of creating instance variable.If its going to help I here is code of my TicTacViewController, where buttons are located:

```
public class TicTacViewController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private Label lblPlayer;

    @FXML
    private Button btnNewGame;

@FXML
private GridPane gridPane;

private static final String TXT_PLAYER = "Player: ";
private IGameModel game = new GameBoard();
@FXML
public Button btn1;
@FXML
public Button btn2;
@FXML
public Button btn3;
@FXML
public Button btn4;
@FXML
public Button btn5;
@FXML
public Button btn6;
@FXML
public Button btn7;
@FXML
public Button btn8;
@FXML
public Button btn9;
```

Comment: At the time the `buttonss` array is initialized, have the TicTacVIewController fields been injected yet with non-null values?

Comment: I think you are not initializing the buttons themselves inside the TicTacViewController class. Check the constructor for that class. If they are not initialized when you create an instance of TicTacViewController , all the button variables will be null and this will throw a NullValueException when you invoke your switchPlayer() method

Comment: This has "code smell" all over it. Using public buttons that are then copied into another array seems like the MVC approach is being violated. I would think working more within the framework would alleviate this issue, and lead to better code.

Comment: Also, the switchPlayer has a bug - it will never switch the currentPlayer if the currentPlayer value is 1 ... the whole code in the method should be in if-else if block instead of two separate if statements

Comment: `tacController`'s fields won't be initialized unless you're using the [*Custom component approach*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) and load the fxml in the constructor of `TicTacViewController`. (Using the "standard fxml structure" `FXMLLoader` creates a new controller instance when loading the fxml; instances of that are created `TicTacViewController` are not "magically" connected somehow.)

Comment: Okay, so I understand that in the moment when I am creating an array buttons are not initialized yet (not connected with the view). But as i said, when I am initializing my array inside a method, buttons are already connected with the view and everything is working. So my question is, why it is not working when we are initializing array as instance variables? I mean if these buttons are reference variables, they should be changing dynamicly when we are for example connecting them to the view, so even if they arent connected when initializing array, they should be when we are invoking method

Comment: To specify - even if in the moment of initialization buttons are not connected and they are null, we are connecting them afterwards. So when we are invoking metgods they already should be initialized, but it looks like buttons reference variables inside arrays are still null. Can someone explain me hy?